# How to achieve a css image grid system

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the following css grid system as in the picture using css. I am not sure what would be the way to do it correctly.

[image]

If there are three images or more, the first child should occupy bigger space, let say 50% and the rest of the children share the rest of the space.

```
.just-3:first-child {
  width:   50% !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  float: left;
}

.just-3:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}
.just-3:nth-child(3) {
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You can use css grid layout to easily solve this. Will take about 15 minutes to learn it's basics and you'll be able to visualize it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your width is larger than 50%; in this regard it is 66.7%.
If you want to use 50%, use it for the height only.

example html:

```
<div>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAQCAYAAADESFVDAAAAF0lEQVR42mN8ay/+n4EAYBxVNKqIOEUAHxwkMbzRAlUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAQCAYAAADESFVDAAAAF0lEQVR42mMUd3v7n4EAYBxVNKqIOEUAjRQkoX/487YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAQCAYAAADESFVDAAAAF0lEQVR42mP8/5fhPwMBwDiqaFQRcYoAP8YvwQxY+AYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
</div>
```

Like this for css:

```
div{
  display:flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:66.67vh;
  height:100vh;
}

img:first-child{
  height:100%;
}
img{
  height:50%;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: you could also wrap the 2 smaller pictures in a div, which gives you more flexibility